# Creating a quiz using php, To store array data in a field in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to create a dynamic quiz and store it in database, the inputs is composed of 1 question and 4 answers. 
I made the textbox and radio buttons dynamically created using jquery. The 1 textbox is for the question and the other 4 textbox is for the answer, I have also 4 radio buttons for correct answer.

```
var ctr = 2;
      $("#addTextBox").click(function() {

      var newTBdiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
          .attr("id", 'QuestionTBDiv' +ctr);

          newTBdiv.css({"margin-top":"20px" });
          newTBdiv.css({"width":"500px"});
          newTBdiv.css({"padding":"5px"});
          newTBdiv.after().html('<label class="mlabel">Question</label><br/><input type="text"  name="quiztxtBox'+ctr+'" size="57" id="quiztxtBox'+ctr+'" placeholder="Question #'+ctr+'"><br/><label class="mlabel">Answer</label><br/><input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="24" id="answer[]" placeholder="Choice A">&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="correct_answer'+ctr+'" value="A">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="answer'+ctr+'" size="24" id="answer'+ctr+'" placeholder="Choice B">&nbsp<input type="radio" name="correct_answer'+ctr+'" value="B"><br/><input type="text" name="answer'+ctr+'" size="24" id="answer'+ctr+'" placeholder="Choice C">&nbsp;<input type="radio" class = "choiceC" name="correct_answer'+ctr+'" value="C">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="answer'+ctr+'"size="24" id="answer'+ctr+'" placeholder="Choice D">&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="correct_answer'+ctr+'" value="D"><br><span name="errMchoice" class="errorMsg"></span>')

          newTBdiv.appendTo("#exam_container");

          ctr++;

    });
```

Now the problem is, I need to store the data of questions and answer to one field only in the database.. I found out that using serialize() function will able to store the array in the field, But Im not quite sure of what I am doing. I was thinking of something like this. This is the array that I was thinking to serialize and store in the database.

```
$array = array(
             array(question1, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, correctanswer);
             array(question1, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, correctanswer);
);
```

Or is there other method to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you store the same thing twice ?

Comment: and why do you want to store in 1 field .. ? why not multiple dedicated tables ...?

Comment: @Bixi, this is because the quiz is dynamic I'm guessing and one cannot easily or sensibly create fields for all possible permutations.

Comment: I am creating more than one quiz. And be able to retrieve it again also to save space and avoid redundancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is update you would use 2 tables to be like this:

table: Quizes

```
id, title, creator, etc
```

table: Quiz_Settings

```
id //(simply for managing rows and edits/updates)
"1", "2", "3" // etc

quiz_id
"55912" // or so on

type
"question", "answer"

ref_number
"1", "2" // This is basically Question 1, Question 2, Answer 1 etc.

value
"What is ...?" or "21" // The question or the answer
```

You would then get quiz by id = 55912, and check against quiz settings for all with "quiz_id" == 55912, and using the "question" field and "ref_number" field, you generate a table or page which has the questions, and then a field which has to be equal to "answer" "1"

In the event of MULTIPLE answers, you simply loop through each "answer" "1", if it's correct, +1, if it's incorrect, 0.

// EXAMPLE JS:

```
<script>
                var num_fields = <?=($num_fields > 0 ? $num_fields : 0)?>;
                var num_multi_fields = <?=($num_multi_fields > 0 ? $num_multi_fields : 0)?>;
                var cf = new Array();
                var cv = new Array();
                <?for($i=1;$i<=$num_fields;$i++) { ?>cf[<?=$i?>] = "<?=${'cf'.$i}?>"; cv[<?=$i?>] = "<?=${'cv'.$i}?>";<? } ?>

                var cmf = new Array();
                <?for($i=1;$i<=$num_multi_fields;$i++) { ?>
                    cmf[<?=$i?>] = "<?=${"cmf".$i}?>";
                    var cmv<?=$i?> = new Array();
                    <?$k = 0; for($j=1;$j<=${"cmf".$i."vt"};$j++) {?>
                        cmv<?=$i?>[<?=$k?>] = "<?=${"cmf".$i."v".$j}?>";
                    <? $k++; } ?>
                <?}  ?>

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#num_fields").val(num_fields);
                    for(i=1;i<=num_fields;i++) {
                        $("#custom_fields").append(
                            '<div id="custom_'+i+'"><br/><label for="custom_field_'+i+'" class="custom-label">Custom Field '+i+': </label>&nbsp;'
                            + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete_custom_o">Delete</button><br />'
                            + '<table width="100%"><tr><td>Field Name:</td><td>Field Value:</td></tr><tr>'
                            + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control custom_field" value="'+cf[i]+'" name="custom_field_'+i+'"/></td>'
                            + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control custom_value" value="'+cv[i]+'" name="custom_value_'+i+'"/></td></tr></table></div>'
                        );
                    };
                    $(".delete_custom_o").click(function() {
                        $(this).parent().remove();
                        var i = 0;
                        $("#custom_fields>div").each(function() {
                            i++;
                            $(this).find('label').text("Custom Field " +i+":");
                            $(this).find('.custom_field').attr("name", "custom_field_"+i);
                            $(this).find('.custom_value').attr("name", "custom_value_"+i);
                        });
                        num_fields--;
                        $("#num_fields").val(num_fields);
                    });
                });

                $("#add_field").click(function() {
                    num_fields++;
                    $("#num_fields").val(num_fields);
                    $("#custom_fields").append(
                        '<div id="custom_'+num_fields+'"><br/><label for="custom_field_'+num_fields+'">Custom Field '+num_fields+':</label>&nbsp;'
                        + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete_custom_n">Delete</button><br />'
                        + '<table width="100%"><tr><td>Field Name:</td><td>Field Value:</td></tr><tr>'
                        + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control custom_field" name="custom_field_'+num_fields+'"/></td>'
                        + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control custom_value" name="custom_value_'+num_fields+'"/></td></tr></table></div>'
                    );
                });
                $('#custom_fields').on("click", ".delete_custom_n", function(){
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                    var i = 0;
                    $("#custom_fields>div").each(function() {
                        i++;
                        $(this).find('label').text("Custom Field " +i+":");
                        $(this).find('.custom_field').attr("name", "custom_field_"+i);
                        $(this).find('.custom_value').attr("name", "custom_value_"+i);
                    });
                    num_fields--;
                    $("#num_fields").val(num_fields);
                });

                $("#add_multi_field").click(function() {
                    num_multi_fields++;
                    $("#num_multi_fields").val(num_multi_fields);
                    $("#custom_multi_fields").append(
                        '<div id="custom_'+num_multi_fields+'" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom: 5px;"><br/>'
                        + '<label for="custom_field_'+num_multi_fields+'">Custom Field '+num_multi_fields+':</label>&nbsp;'
                        + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs em-bg-blue add_custom_n" data-id="'+num_multi_fields+'" data-target="#custom_table_'+num_multi_fields+'">Add</button>&nbsp;'
                        + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete_custom_n">Delete</button><br />'
                        + '<div style="max-height:100px; overflow-y:auto; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><table width="100%" id="custom_table_'+num_multi_fields+'"><tr><td>Field Name:</td><td>Field Value:</td></tr><tr>'
                        + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control custom_field" name="custom_multi_field_'+num_multi_fields+'"/></td>'
                        + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control custom_value" name="custom_multi_value_'+num_multi_fields+'[]"/></td></tr>'
                        + '<tr><td><center><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete_field">Remove</button></center></td>'
                        + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control custom_value" name="custom_multi_value_'+num_multi_fields+'[]"/></td></tr></table></div></div>'
                    );
                });
                $('#custom_multi_fields').on("click", ".add_custom_n", function(){
                    target = $(this).attr('data-target');
                    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    $(target).find('tbody')
                        .append($('<tr>')
                            .append($('<td>').html('<center><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete_field">Remove</button></center>'))
                            .append($('<td>')
                                .append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('class', 'form-control custom_value').attr('name', 'custom_multi_value_'+id+'[]'))
                            )
                        );
                });
                $('#custom_multi_fields').on("click", ".delete_field", function(){
                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove(); 
                });
                $('#custom_multi_fields').on("click", ".delete_custom_n", function(){
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                    var i = 0;
                    $("#custom_multi_fields>div").each(function() {
                        i++;
                        $(this).find('label').attr('for','custom_field_'+i).text("Custom Field " +i+":");
                        $(this).attr('id','custom_'+i);
                        $(this).find('button.add_custom_n').attr('data-target', '#custom_table_'+i).attr('data-id', i);
                        $(this).find('table').attr("id","custom_table_"+i);
                        $(this).find('.custom_field').attr("name","custom_multi_field_"+i);
                        $(this).find('.custom_value').attr("name","custom_multi_value_"+i+"[]");
                    });
                    num_multi_fields--;
                    $("#num_multi_fields").val(num_multi_fields);
                });

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#num_multi_fields").val(num_multi_fields);
                    for(i=1;i<=num_multi_fields;i++) {
                        var curr_array = window['cmv' + i];
                        string = "";
                        for(j=1;j<curr_array.length;j++) {
                            string += '<tr><td><center><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete_field">Remove</button></center></td>'
                                + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control custom_value" value="'+curr_array[j]+'" name="custom_multi_value_'+i+'[]"/></td></tr>'
                        }
                        $("#custom_multi_fields").append(
                            '<div id="custom_'+i+'" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom: 5px;"><br/>'
                            + '<label for="custom_field_'+i+'">Custom Field '+i+':</label>&nbsp;'
                            + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs em-bg-blue add_custom_n" data-id="'+i+'" data-target="#custom_table_'+i+'">Add</button>&nbsp;'
                            + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete_custom_n">Delete</button><br />'
                            + '<div style="max-height:100px; overflow-y:auto; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><table width="100%" id="custom_table_'+i+'"><tr><td>Field Name:</td><td>Field Value:</td></tr></tr>'
                            + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control custom_field" value="'+cmf[i]+'" name="custom_multi_field_'+i+'"/></td>'
                            + '<td><input type="text" class="form-control custom_value" value="'+curr_array[0]+'" name="custom_multi_value_'+i+'[]"/></td></tr>'
                            + ""+string+""
                            + '</table></div></div>'
                        );
                    };
                    $(".delete_custom_o").click(function() {
                        $(this).parent().remove();
                        var i = 0;
                        $("#custom_multi_fields>div").each(function() {
                            i++;
                            $(this).find('label').attr('for','custom_field_'+i).text("Custom Field " +i+":");
                            $(this).attr('id','custom_'+i);
                            $(this).find('button.add_custom_n').attr('data-target', '#custom_table_'+i).attr('data-id', i);
                            $(this).find('table').attr("id","custom_table_"+i);
                            $(this).find('.custom_field').attr("name","custom_multi_field_"+i);
                            $(this).find('.custom_value').attr("name","custom_multi_value_"+i+"[]");
                        });
                        num_multi_fields--;
                        $("#num_multi_fields").val(num_multi_fields);
                    });
                    $(".delete_field").click(function() {
                        $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove(); 
                    });
                });

            </script>
```

The Example HTML: Custom Field = 1 to 1 relationship (1 question 1 answer) - Multi Field = 1 to many relationship (1 question multiple answers)

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn em-bg-blue" id="add_field">Add Custom Field</button><br />
                    <div id="custom_fields" style="max-height: 500px; overflow-y: auto;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn em-bg-blue" id="add_multi_field">Add Multi Field</button><br />
                    <div id="custom_multi_fields" style="max-height: 500px; overflow-y: auto;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: +1 This is certainly on the right track.  Personally I would have 3 tables, one for quizzes, one called `questions` linking questions, their ordering and ther other data to the `quizzes` table and then another with `answers` linking to the other two.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, and it is a lot more efficient in my eyes, but I also like to ensure that I keep my tables as minimal as possible, mainly because most of my applications start racking up a large amount of tables. Habbit, mostly, but yes, a 3rd table just for answers may be more beneficial.

Comment: hmm.. I was thinking to store them in array, coz it will occupy too much fields, for example, I have 10 quiz, and each quiz has 100 questions. It will occupy too much right?

Comment: The point of databases are to store large amounts of data, however, if you really want to keep it small, you could store them in an array, then json_encode it, and when needed, json_decode it

Comment: it is the same as serialize and unserialize right? 
now the problem is my inputs, can u give me an idea on how to post the correct data?

Comment: Well I'd recommend using a HTML Array, `<input name="answers[]">` - this allows you to post multiple values using the same name, should be a lot easier to manage.

Comment: Im having problem storing the question and answer since they are in the same field.

Comment: You're setting a value of "question" or "answer" to a field called "type", and in the ref_number you're setting the number "1" and so forth. This allow you to have multiple answers for each question also.

Comment: Also this will require some fancy JS/jQuery - I've edited my answer with a portion of script I done previously for something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is an alright method. Have a look at the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) library, or try to write a very simple [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) file that will serialize for you.

Comment: Yes, but Im having problem with my inputs, seems like it is not the proper way.